# how to optimize SQL queries using IN having indexed keys

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain, where-in

I am running this query

`EXPLAIN SELECT id, timestamp from foo where id IN (23,67,78,90) order by ASC`

here `id` is indexed. But then too when I am running `Explain` I am getting  this in `Using where;Using Index` in `Extra`

```
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | foo   | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |   12  | Using where;Using Index|
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

But when I am running this same query with single `id` nothing is in `Extra` its working as expected in the case of index

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id, timestamp from foo where id = 23`

+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table| type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | foo | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |  1 |        |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

I think something wrong with IN. Can anyone tell me the way to optimize it ?

Comment: I'm confused.  How do you think the query could find those rows without some kind of search of the rows using the index?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9534935/1919238

Comment: It says it's using the index. That means it's optimized.

Comment: One more thing added... now to what extent It will affect the execution time ?

Comment: Something strange is going on -- why "range" for simply "id=23".  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge,

IN query will take more time than Single "=". If "IN" have single value then it is equal to single "=" query.

Because it is MULTIPLE OR conditions of "=" OR "=".

id will match with every 4 values in "IN" array.

```
Only way to optimise is to have index.
```

Update:

If the Extra column also says `Using where`, it means the index is being used to perform lookups of key values. Without Using where, the optimizer may be reading the index to avoid reading data rows but not using it for lookups. For example, if the index is a covering index for the query, the optimizer may scan it without using it for lookups. See [explanation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html)

Comment: everything is indexed but the problem is even after indexing it is showing `Using where` in `extra` in `expain` it shouldn't be showing `using where`

Comment: Its means it can't be more optimized