# Store user comments in database

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm facing some performance issues with MySql. The query to select the comments related to the specific url id took about 1.5 ~ 2 seconds to complete.

### Comments Table

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
    `id`                INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `url_id`            INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `user_id`           INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `published`         TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `votes_up`          SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `votes_down`        SMALLINT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `text`              TEXT,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX (url_id),
    INDEX (user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have inserted 100.000 comments, and executed this query: `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE url_id = 33 ORDER BY published ASC LIMIT 0,5`.

Is this normal? A simple query taking almost 2 seconds to complete? Should I create a separate table just for the comment's text?

Youtube, Facebook and so on has millions (or billions) of comments, how they get the comments for that object (video, post, etc) so fast?

To resume my question:

1. I stop worrying about performance and stick with this and when the website reaches certain amount of user activity, I start worrying about this.
2. If I need to worry about this, what's wrong to my table structure? What I need to change to reduce the completion time of that query?

#### Update

The `explain` output:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | comments | ref  | url_id        | url_id   | 4       | const |  549 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Look into "explain", using and understanding it will help you figure out what's wrong with your queries. Have you tried an index on "published"?

Comment: Using `SMALLINT` is asking for trouble. That thing's going to overflow in a hurry. Use `INT` unless you have some very compelling reason to use something else.

Comment: The companies you cite tend to have large datacenters with redundant cutting edge servers being used to pull data, and highly qualified DBAs to structure their datasets in ways to pull data fast. The differences between your setup and theirs is most likely going to be craptons of money and years of experience.

Comment: @JimL I added index on `published`, same thing =/.

Comment: @cteski hmm, you think I should follow @salvation-oba and leave that way? @tadman these `SMALLINT` field are "like" and "dislike", I doubt there will be a comment that will exceed 32.767 likes or dislikes.

Comment: @Kirito94 please add the explain output for the query to the post. See this post for info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120765/understanding-mysql-explain-output

Comment: @JimL added the explain output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that mysql uses only one index per table. That's why your index on `published` wasn't used. Your `explain` shows that it's using the index to identify what rows to return, that leaves the RDBMS unable to use an index for the sorting.

What you should do is to create a composite index on `(user_id,published)`

Comment: Works perfectly. Execution time is 10 ~ 20ms.