# Using Where during Explain for MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have a table when making a query,

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `id`
FROM `tblsender`
WHERE `userid` = '6'
AND `astatus` = '1'
AND `sender` = 'ABCDEF'
```

I am getting `USING WHERE` even after indexing in all possible ways. Here is my final table structure code.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblsender` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`sender` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
`astatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`userid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `astatus` (`astatus`),
KEY `userid` (`userid`),
KEY `sender` (`sender`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=22975 ;
```

I even tried full text for `sender` column but still no luck and I also tried indexing on all `where clause` columns.

```
ALTER TABLE `tblsender` ADD INDEX ( `sender` , `astatus` , `userid` ) ;
```

Still getting `using where`, how can I properly index this table.

Edit: Explain output for above structure.

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys           key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE      tblsender   ref     astatus,userid,sender   astatus     1       const   1       Using where
```

and Explain output for all 3 columns together

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys                   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      tblsender   ref     astatus,userid,sender,sender_2  astatus     1       const   1       Using where
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533841/mysql-fix-using-where

Comment: Pleaae show the output from `EXPLAIN` when all three columns are included in a single index.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, sorry for late reply as I had some internet connection issues. I have updated my question.

Comment: You pass userid and astatus as strings; omit the apostrophe.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler does it help in anyway?

Comment: @zed, as per your reference, shouldn't I be bothered when `using where`, right?

Comment: @yuri1000 Yes. I haven't seen this before so I cannot comment on my own behalf.

Comment: @yuri1000 the index knows the datatype of the column. If you pass another datatype the data has to be cast to the correct type. It might be it therfore does not use the index.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler i tried without quote too, the results are same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't effectively predict optimizer behavior on large data sets when testing with small data sets.

As illustrated by the query plans, the multi column index is seen as a candidate, but the optimizer is choosing not to use it *in this case*.  That doesn't mean it won't use it when it will be considered more beneficial.

I can only speculate without seeing your actual data set and perhaps using [optimizer tracing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-tracing.html), but I'll offer a reasonable speculation.

The optimizer in MySQL is cost-based.  It tries to resolve your query in the least costly way possible.  Note that `rows` = 1.  This means that the optimizer has concluded that -- statistically, at least -- it expects that only 1 row is going to match in the index on `astatus`.  With `key_len` = 1, meaning that `astatus` is only 1 byte wide -- as opposed to the multicolumn index, which is 11 bytes wide (1 + 6 + 4) -- the `astatus` index looks like a really inexpensive solution, so it decides to go with that index.  Using the longer index theoretically means more I/O, therefore more costly, though in this case (because of a small data set) we humans recognize that the cost difference isn't particularly meaningful.

`Using where` means that for each row actually returned by using that index, the server will need to verify that the rows match the remainder of the `WHERE` clause, but if we're only expecting approximately 1 row to match, it's no big deal.

I suggest, then, that you do not have cause for concern, because the small size of the current data set is not going to be able to give you useful information in predicting future behavior.  In this specific case, `Using where` is an artifact of the small number of rows in the table.

You need more data.  But yes, you do want a multicolumn index here.

Comment: I have 22k rows in that table. As you explained, probably where clause needs to return just one row, then its not using the index columns. Table has 192kb data, may be you are right, its just not using the index. Thanks for taking time to explain.

Comment: @yuri1000 it is also possible that you would get different results if you first run `ANALYZE TABLE` on the table.  The index statistics may be providing less than ideal hints back to the optimizer.